# React + ES6: defaultProps of hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Due I refactor my code to ES6, I move all defaults to `SomeClass.defaultProps = { ... }`.

Suppose a situation, when there is a class hierarchy, and I need to keep some defaults to whole hierarchy. But the ***problem*** is that `defaultProps` not work for classes that are extended:

```
class AbstractComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { super(props) }
}
class OneOfImplementations extends AbstractComponent {
  constructor(props) { super(props) }
}
//Problem: hierarchy defaults doesn't work
AbstractComponent.defaultProps = { name: 'Super' }
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/102/)

**P.S.** I'm wondering where is the best place to keep commons (variables/functions) for the whole hierarchy? Maybe do something like this at `AbstractComponent`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(_.assign(props, {
    commonValue: 128,
    commonCallback: _.noop
  }));
}
```

But the problem is that's become impossible to override one of properties from a subclass

Comment: I'm pretty sure react recommends avoiding this sort of extending of one's own classes actually

Comment: @Joshua please explain what you mean. Which sort of extending?

Comment: This bit `class OneOfImplementations extends AbstractComponent {` I'm fairly sure I saw spicyj saying should be avoided, i.e. everything should extend `React.Component`

Comment: I'm trying to find it, but can't find the github issue

Comment: What with the ES6 syntax not supporting mixins, abstracting functionality is a bit unknown, but it looks like the `@decorator` syntax might be the preferred option - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5010

Comment: @Joshua that's strange, I really whant to see some arguments against subclassing custom components

Comment: Yeah, I really wish I could find it... I'm pretty sure it's just has some potential issues associated with it (e.g. this), but if you can get it to work, fair enough

Comment: I think this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/103/

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Did you work out a way to do this?

Comment: @bugfixr currently Sorry, I do not remember. I've switched to backend development, I haven't been writing front-end almost for a year

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively if you're using the <strike>stage: 0</strike> `stage: 2` preset in Babel (or the [transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) directly) you can use es7's proposed static property:

```
class AbstractComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  static defaultProps = { name: 'Super' }

  // Bonus: you can also set instance properties like this
  state = {
    someState: true,
  }

  // ^ Combined with new arrow binding syntax, you often don't need
  // to override the constructor (for state or .bind(this) reasons)
  onKeyPress = () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I haven't es7 support

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the order of declaration of the "defaultProps" property is important:

```
class AbstractComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { super(props) }

  render() {
    return <div>Prop: [ {this.props.name} ]</div>
  }
}
AbstractComponent.defaultProps = { name: 'Super' }

class ComponentImpl1 extends AbstractComponent {
  constructor(props) { super(props) }
}

// works
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/103/

Comment: thanks! But my case look like this http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/104/. Because `OneOfImplementations ` is required first, and then require `AbstractComponent` as dependncy

Comment: JS is a scripting language. Order is important.
http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2753/